# change "add" icon to "add-circle" icon when users click on it

Tags: html, angular, ionic4

I'm new to coding and I need the "add" Icon to be replaced with "add-circle" icon when users click on it. please help me. Below is the addToCart method in my ts file, what do I have to add in here to replace properly? Please help me

```
  <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
          <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>
          Courses
        </ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of courseList">
          <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
            <img [src]=item.picture>
          </ion-thumbnail>
          <ion-label>
          <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
          <p> {{item.price | currency}}</p>
          <ion-button size="small" id="adding" (click)=addToCart(item)>
            <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="add"></ion-icon>
          </ion-button>
        </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>


    </ion-content>

  async addToCart(item: Course) {
    this.cartService.add(item);
    const toast = await this.toastController.create({
      message: item.title + ' added to compare',
      duration: 2000,
      position: 'top',
      color: 'secondary'
    });
    toast.present();    
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a variable that has an icon name

```
 public icon: string;
```

and initialize the `icon` variable in the constructor

```
  constructor() {
    this.icon = 'add';
    });
  }
```

and in the `addToCart()` method assign new add-circle icon

```
addToCart(item){
  this.icon ="add-circle"
}
```

and finally in the html file

```
<ion-icon name="{{icon}}"></ion-icon>
```

[Live Demo](https://ionic-axd6ip.stackblitz.io)

Answer (score 1):

Html file

```
<ion-icon [name]="addCircleIcon" (click)='addCircle()'></ion-icon>
```

Declare a variable an icon name:

```
addCircleIcon: string = 'add-icon';
```

click() function:

```
addCircle() {
             this.addCircleIcon = this.addCircleIcon === 'add-icon' ? 'add-icon-circle' : 'add-icon';
            }
```